OSGi application upgrade from Postgres 11/12 to Postgres 15
My OSGi application has been running with a Postgres driver that works Postgres 11 without problems. Oddly, everything has been working so I have had little to deal with the libraries needed. I believe what I have been using is:
org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5
Using OSGi R7
I thought there was a jpa.persistence but can't find that in my setup.
I am working on upgrading my Postgres to version 15. In the process, I get the error below. I think this is being thrown as I need to upgrade to use a compatible driver for this postgres version.
Is anyone using OSGi R7 with Postgres 15?
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.JPADataSourceHelper.poolIfNecessary(JPADataSourceHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa.impl.XAJPADataSourceSetup.decorateJPAProperties(XAJPADataSourceSetup.java:68)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.lambda$addingService$0(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:95)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.updateService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:181)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:124)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:57)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.start(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:102)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.updateService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:125)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:104)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:44)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:264)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.start(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:83)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.resource.common.impl.ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.updated(ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$UpdateConfiguration.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1400)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:138)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:105)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:409)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:94)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:46)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:33)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jdbc.xa.connection.impl.XADataSourceMapper.getConnection(XADataSourceMapper.java:80)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/sasl/SaslException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:364)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException not found by org.postgresql.jdbc42 [85]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
2024-05-10 18:51:36.891| ERROR|The configuration driven resource for pid org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa~persistenceTarget encountered a failure|org.apache.aries.tx.control.resource.common.impl.ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An error occurred when creating the connection provider
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.updateService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:130)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:104)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:44)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:264)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.start(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:83)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.resource.common.impl.ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.updated(ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$UpdateConfiguration.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1400)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:138)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:105)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.JPADataSourceHelper.poolIfNecessary(JPADataSourceHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa.impl.XAJPADataSourceSetup.decorateJPAProperties(XAJPADataSourceSetup.java:68)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.lambda$addingService$0(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:95)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.updateService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:181)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:124)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:57)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.start(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:102)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.updateService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:125)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:409)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:94)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:46)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:33)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jdbc.xa.connection.impl.XADataSourceMapper.getConnection(XADataSourceMapper.java:80)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/sasl/SaslException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:364)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException not found by org.postgresql.jdbc42 [85]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
*ERROR* [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=22, bundle=27/file:/C:/Users/jhray/.m2/repository/org/apache/aries/tx-control/tx-control-provider-jpa-xa/1.0.0/tx-control-provider-jpa-xa-1.0.0.jar]: Updating configuration org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa~persistenceTarget caused a problem: A failure occured configuring the resource for pid org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa~persistenceTarget
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: null : A failure occured configuring the resource for pid org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa~persistenceTarget
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.resource.common.impl.ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.updated(ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.updated(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:159)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceFactoryTracker.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$UpdateConfiguration.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1400)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:138)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:105)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An error occurred when creating the connection provider
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.updateService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:130)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:104)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.addingService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:44)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:264)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.start(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:83)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.resource.common.impl.ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.updated(ConfigurationDefinedResourceFactory.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:516)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.JPADataSourceHelper.poolIfNecessary(JPADataSourceHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.xa.impl.XAJPADataSourceSetup.decorateJPAProperties(XAJPADataSourceSetup.java:68)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.lambda$addingService$0(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:95)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.updateService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:181)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:124)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.addingService(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:57)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:871)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:321)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.start(AbstractManagedJPAEMFLocator.java:102)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jpa.common.impl.AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.updateService(AbstractManagedJPADataSourceSetup.java:125)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:409)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:94)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:46)
    at org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource.getXAConnection(PGXADataSource.java:33)
    at org.apache.aries.tx.control.jdbc.xa.connection.impl.XADataSourceMapper.getConnection(XADataSourceMapper.java:80)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:316)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/sasl/SaslException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2344)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClassParallel(BundleWiringImpl.java:2162)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2096)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1565)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:364)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException not found by org.postgresql.jdbc42 [85]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 27 more
2024-05-10 18:51:40.650| WARN |Not monitoring system resources [Windows 10]|com.mako.core.health.manager.MakoResourceMonitor


Did the database server start? (check logfiles) Can you connect to the database using psql or any other SQL client? What PostgreSQL driver do you use?

javax.security.sasl.SaslException class can't be found. It's part of JDK, so you're missing javax.security.sasl package in org.osgi.framework.system.packages property - it can be configured in Felix and in Karaf and in any OSGi runtime.
